# Check if condition in react map function

Tags: reactjs

I have working code and a little problem with the if statement in the map function here is code.

```
<main className="grid-b">
    {offers.map((offers,index)=> {
        if(offers.status==='pending')
        return
        <
        <article>
            <div className="text-b">
                <h3>Post ID: {index + 1}</h3>
                <p>Quantity (Kg): {offers.quantity}</p>
                <p>Unit Price (Rs): {offers.value}</p>
                <p>Expiry Date: {moment(offers.expiryDate).fromNow()}</p>
                <p>Offer Gives: {moment(offers.offerCreatedAt).fromNow()}</p>
            </div>
        </article>
        />
    })}
</main>
```

Now I want to check if the statement to render only when in map offers.status==='pending' if not, does not show anything. But this code does not work. How should I solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the same variable name (`offers`) in both the map and the parent function which is likely the issue. Change the map variable to something like `offer` and it should work as intended. You also have a typo in your mapped render.

e.g.

```
<main className="grid-b">
    {offers.map((offer,index)=> {
        if(offer.status==='pending')
        return (
          <article>
            <div className="text-b">
                <h3>Post ID: {index + 1}</h3>
                <p>Quantity (Kg): {offer.quantity}</p>
                <p>Unit Price (Rs): {offer.value}</p>
                <p>Expiry Date: {moment(offer.expiryDate).fromNow()}</p>
                <p>Offer Gives: {moment(offer.offerCreatedAt).fromNow()}</p>
            </div>
          </article>
        );
    })}
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to use the same name in the arrow function. Note the following changes:

```
<main className="grid-b">
    {offers.map((offer,index)=> 
        offer.status==='pending' &&(
        <article>
            <div className="text-b">
                <h3>Post ID: {index + 1}</h3>
                <p>Quantity (Kg): {offers.quantity}</p>
                <p>Unit Price (Rs): {offers.value}</p>
                <p>Expiry Date: {moment(offers.expiryDate).fromNow()}</p>
                <p>Offer Gives: {moment(offers.offerCreatedAt).fromNow()}</p>
            </div>
        </article>
    ))}
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can filter the offers list.

```
offers.filter(offer => offer.status==='pending').map((offer,index)=> {

}
```